# Can someone tell me what this comedian is saying I cannot make out the words

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbOA5b4Y7T8

Please go to the joke at 1:38

The words he says after "jake what's gonna be..."

I wish comments were on by the youtube video so I could ask there

Thank you

Comment: We don't really offer a transcription service here.

Comment: We don't really offer a transcription service here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I can hear, although I have no absolute certitude about the last word in the question.

- And for a story I've been associated with what seems like a hundred years… The two partners sit in the office one morning and one says the other Jake "what's gonna be with the Taft-Hartley bill issues ? Pay a dollar!

Comment: well your reply with the words taft-harley made me google those word. Seems it was some legal bill and the job is that the partner asks whats gonna be with this bill and he was told to pay it the he-ll with it